# Pegar valor em laço Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso imprimir o valor de cada alt no for?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pai">

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt1">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt2">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt3">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt4">
    </div>

</div>


<style>

.filho {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<script>

var elementos = $('.pai .filho');
var countElementos = elementos.length;
var intervalo = 1;
var comeco = 0;

for(var i = comeco; i < countElementos; i += intervalo) {
    var teste = $(elementos[i].className).attr('alt');
    console.log(teste);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que, com a linha abaixo:

> ```
>  var teste = $(elementos[i].className).attr('alt');
> ```

Você está selecionando a `div` em que a imagem está contida. Logo, quando você captura o atributo `alt` desse elemento, você não recebe nada, já que a `div` não possui atributo `alt`.

Logo, você poderia corrigir o código selecionando as imagens:

```
var elementos = $('.pai .filho > img');
```

Ficando assim:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pai">

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt1">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt2">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt3">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt4">
    </div>

</div>


<style>

.filho {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<script>

var elementos = $('.pai .filho > img');
var countElementos = elementos.length;
var intervalo = 1;
var comeco = 0;

for(var i = comeco; i < countElementos; i += intervalo) {
    var teste = $(elementos[i]).attr('alt');
    console.log(teste);
}

</script>
```

Se você quiser buscar o elemento filho dentro do laço `for`, pode fazer assim:

```js
var elementos = $('.pai .filho');
var countElementos = elementos.length;
var intervalo = 1;
var comeco = 0;

for(var i = comeco; i < countElementos; i += intervalo) {
    // Note abaixo que adicionei o "children".
    // Também removi o `className`, já que o `elementos[i]` já é suficiente para que o jQuery reconheça o elemento:
    var teste = $(elementos[i]).children('img').attr('alt');
    console.log(teste);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pai">
    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt1">
    </div>
    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt2">
    </div>
    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt3">
    </div>
    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso resolveria, mas a logica seria acessar o elemento pai pra depois buscar o filho, no caso o alt

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando mais um exemplo ao final. Seria isso? ;)

Comment: children! exatamente isso, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Já que está usando jQuery, poderia usar o `.each()`:

```js
$(".pai .filho").each(function(){
   var teste = $("img", this).attr("alt");
   console.log(teste);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pai">

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt1">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt2">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt3">
    </div>

    <div class='filho'>
        <img alt="alt4">
    </div>

</div>
```

O código `$("img", this).attr("alt")` irá buscar em cada elemento `.filho` dentro de `.pai` a tag `img` e seu respectivo atributo `alt`.